# What is the use of By the time?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

What is the best way of using By the time ? I searched in google where there wasn't exact example ?

Comment: This isn't enough information to respond.  Context?  Source?  Anything?

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/time

Comment: I'm sorry, this is an English language board about the English language.  You'll need to make comments and ask questions in English for them to be answered.  "Checked on this portal even i didn't get answer" is not an intelligible English sentence.

Comment: @RameshMuthiah, do check out: http://www.ell.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When A has occurred, B will be true.

"By the time you read this answer, you will already understand."

[By the time](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=by+the+time)

Comment: This is good. Could you please give me another example ?

Comment: Have you room clean by the time I get home, or you'll be in trouble.

Comment: By the time the shuttle reached the space station, Commander Hadfield was ready to stretch his legs.